# C# RichTextBox Paste adding in extra characters

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, copy-paste

My assignment program has Cut, Copy and Paste methods for rich text in a richtextbox. However, when I Copy and then Paste, I'm getting extra characters and numbers pasted and I don't know where they're coming from.

Are my Cut, Copy and Paste methods incorrect? I have done a lot of searching, but I can't seem to pinpoint the issue. My test file has the words "test" or "Testing" in a few lines, but when I Paste, I get things like "ng1033" pasted in.

```
private void cutText()
{
    Clipboard.Clear();
    if(desktopRichText.SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        //cut selected text to clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText(desktopRichText.SelectedRtf);
        desktopRichText.SelectedRtf = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select text to modify");
    }

}

private void copyText()
{
    Clipboard.Clear();
    if(desktopRichText.SelectionLength > 0)
    {
        //copies selected text to clipboard
        Clipboard.SetText(desktopRichText.SelectedRtf);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select text to modify");
    }

}

private void pasteText()
{
    if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
    {
        //pastes text on clipboard to richtextbox
        string cutText = Clipboard.GetText();
        desktopRichText.SelectedRtf = desktopRichText.SelectedRtf.Insert(desktopRichText.SelectionStart, cutText);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select text to modify");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe 1033 is the return chars? trim the text?

Comment: Hm, I just tried putting Trim() into Cut, Copy and Paste methods, but the paste still pastes the extra characters. I notice Paste doesn't work after Copy sometimes as well.

Answer (score 1):

To do copy, cut or paste in `RichTextBox`, use the corresponding methods of the control:

- [Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.copy(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Cut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.cut(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.paste(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Example**

```
private void CopyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
        richTextBox1.Copy();
}
private void CutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength > 0)
        richTextBox1.Cut();
}
private void PasteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
        richTextBox1.Paste();
}
```